# Is it possible to take a javascript array and SAVE it to a file server-side?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a project where Im using a windows hosting environment and classic asp / vbscript and need to take a Javascript array that is created dynamically and save it to a local file ( "somefilename_unique-ID-I-will-add.js" )...  I've used fso in the past to create dynamic log files on a couple of projects but am unsure where to begin in terms of figuring out how to take the js array and 'give' it to or access it in .asp / vbscript especially since the .asp runs before any javascript / jquery is run.

Anyone have any idea a) if its do-able and b) how to go about it?

the resulting .js file on the server will be used as the json or jsonp data source for an android and ios app.

Thanks for any light anyone can shed on this.

Comment: Create a JSON string from your js array, and then POST it to your ASP page using a form or jquery.  It will arrive at your ASP page as a string, which you can then save to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.. You would need to create an API method (search for ASP web method) and post the array to the server via an AJAX call.  You could then construct the file server side within the web method.

Here is a link for an example of `[WebMethod]` :

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

If this project is OK with a trip to the server, then you can merely submit a form where the onLoad of the page used JavaScript to fill some hidden form fields with the values from your array. Or even use a querystring, i.e., sender_page.asp?data001=blahblah&data002=blahdeblah&data003=blahdoobleeblah...